# Display product name on sendfriend page

Tags: magento

I need to pull in the product name and display it at the top of the send to a friend page template.

So, when a user clicks on send to a friend from a product page it (the product name) is at the top of the send to a friend page, above the form itself. Not in the email template (although that is useful - I have seen answers on this elsewhere).

I am very new to Magento and have been asked to do a few modifications and tidy up a few things, but am really a front end dev and have no Magento experience. Any pointers in the right direction would be great help to me.

Also, could anyone recommend a decent Magento Developer book that a Front End Developer with good HTML, CSS & JavaScript (but not so great PHP) would find useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the sendfriend template in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sendfriend/send.phtml
to your theme. Then you can modify it. You shouldn't modify magento core files.

You can print the product name wih `echo Mage::registry('product')->getName();` The product is added to the registry in `Mage_Sendfriend_ProductController`.

Comment: Worked great. I knew it would be a tiny bit of php. Do you have a recommendation of a good Magento tutorial/book that would include things like this. Bear in mind I am really  Front End Developer... (solid HTML, CSS & JavaScript - not so good PHP)

Comment: Maybe you know Alan Storm already. He wrote a book about magento layout: [no-frills-magento-layout](http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/no-frills-magento-layout) After that you should know how the magento template system works.